# Expected gain or loss in roulette

Tags: probability, expected-value, gambling

The questions reads:

> There are $37$ numbers, from $0$ to $36$. Each number has an equal chance of turning up. Zero is green in color and odd numbers are in black and even numbers are in red. If you place $\$1$ on red (black) you get $2$ dollars if you are right and $\$0$ if you are wrong. For each bet there are $19$ losing numbers and $18$ winning numbers.
>
> Suppose you place $\$1$ bets $18$ times on red. What is your expected gain or loss after $18$ tries?

My working:

Expected value of one game = $$2\left(\frac{18}{37}\right) + (-1)\left(\frac{19}{37}\right)$$

Expected value of 18 games = $$\left(2\left(\frac{18}{37}\right) + (-1)\left(\frac{19}{37}\right)\right)^{18}$$

Is this right?

Part $2$:

> Suppose I use a dollar for each color bet? How many games can I play if I have an initial capital of $18?

Not sure how to start on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the right way to go about it, but there are two bugs:

- The value of a win is $1$, not $2$.
- The expected outcome after $18$ rounds is $18$ times the expected expected outcome after $1$ round, by [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).

Comment: I don't understand what "I use a dollar for each color bet" means.

Comment: You place a dollar bet on either color.

Comment: Are you asking about the [expected stopping time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopping_time)?  I'll need to think a bit about that.  My guess would be that it's the minimium $k$ such that $k\times \mathbb{E}[\text{outcome after 1 game}] \leq -18$.

Comment: since a dollar for each colour bet, do i need to multiply the outcome of each game *2?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the change in the total money will either be +1 or -1 after betting $1.

Comment: what i mean is, in the first example, i only consider the red scenario. In the second part, there is also the chance for black part. so do i need to multiply the outcome of each game *2?

Comment: do you get what u mean?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I'm sorry.  Why would we need to multiply anything by 2?

Comment: in the first example, i only consider the red scenario. In the second part, there is also the chance for black part. so do i need to multiply the outcome of each game *2?

Answer (score 0):

We can think of the game as a $1$-dimensional **random walk** where we take a step $+1$ (when we win $\$1$) with probability $p := \frac{18}{37}$ and a step $-1$ (when we lose $\$1$) with probability $1-p = \frac{19}{37}$.

The expected profit after $n$ plays is

$$(2 p - 1) \, n  = \left(\frac{36}{37} - 1\right) n = -\frac{n}{37}$$

which is negative, as expected. If $n = 18$, then the expected **loss** is $\frac{18}{37}$ dollars, which is approximately $50$ cents.